I'm getting an error message when updating my apt and apt-get package manager, how can I solve it?
When updating my package manager with apt and/or apt-get I get this error: (The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.), how can I solve it?

Don't forget PPAs are 3rd party sources, so any security checks on those resources are those you perform yourself... Did you perform any?  as https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-desktop/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntu-make shows rather clearly no attention was spent there since 2018, and no support is offered on any supported release of Ubuntu, so why was it added?  Remove it.
